# Optimising DRF Serialization

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am facing a problem where I have to optimise the serialization of the ORM object. I have an object say `Foo` for which I have a huge serializer. I have mentioned a lot of fields, like

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="bar")
    apple = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="bar.food")
    cat = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="bar.animals.pet")
    ball = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="bar.toy")
    # a lot of other complex fields related with Foo
    # direct-indirect, 1-1 or 1-M relations
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['bar', 'apple', 'cat', 'ball', ....]
```

Now, this is causing the serialisation to take a lot of time. I added logging and saw many SQL queries getting executed. A lot these queries are repeated. As per my understanding from documentations, even though Django QuerySet is lazily executed, the serialization in DRF is querying for each field to get populated. Please elaborate on how serialization fields are populated on lower level as well as it will help me more.

What I want to achieve here is do minimal possible queries. In the example above, To get `bar.food` and `bar.toy` I want to do only one single query which will fetch `bar` object and I can access `food` and `toy` object.

One possible solution I can think of is evaluating all related objects and pass them in context. That is, evaluate `bar` object and send it as a context. Then my `apple` field will be populated as `self.context['bar'].food` in a `SerializerMethodField`. Can you suggest a better way? May be a batch processing?

Assume:
The serialised data is hot and we cannot cache it.

Edit:
Current SQL queries being done are in double digits for each serialisation.

Edit (Query as requested by Daneil)

```
SELECT `app_foo`.`id`, `app_foo`.`field_1`, (many app_foo fields),
`app_foo`.`created_at`, `app_foo`.`updated_at` FROM `app_foo` INNER JOIN
`app_bar` ON `app_foo`.`id` = `app_bar`.`id` WHERE `app_foo`.`id` = 12; args(12,)
```

Comment: Can you add your query too?

Comment: @daneilJames I cannot add all the queries as there are a lot of them. I have an instance when total queries reached 250+. I am adding a sample query in question. All queries are auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

Dear NIkhil Please try using prefetch select and select related

The result cache of the primary QuerySet and all specified related objects will then be fully loaded into memory. This changes the typical behavior of QuerySets, which normally try to avoid loading all objects into memory before they are needed, even after a query has been executed in the database.
More detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: I cannot `prefetch` or `select_related` because the queries I mentioned are being executed to fill the fields. If I fetch `bar` object before calling Serializer, will the serializer query DB to fetch `bar` object again?

Comment: Basically serializer are way to take input and give response so Everything remains in Query  Since you are saying you got 250 queries there must be certain tables that are being touched   on each query. So you must optimize your query first.

Comment: If I were you I would send all my source you are using = in serializer from view side without giving source in serializer.

Comment: "there must be certain tables that are being touched on each query. So you must optimize your query first." This makes sense to me. I will try pulling all fields in one big query and serialize accordingly.

Comment: try making a query that gives you whole context and move towards its inner logic without actually accessing database table instead use the variable that you are storing to keep the whole context query